# org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: An invalid return type "class [B" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer"

Tags: mule, cxf

I am using CXF component in Mule to consume a webserice. I am getting the following error with Mule 3.8

```
Message               : An invalid return type "class [B" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer"
Transformer           : JAXBMarshallerTransformer{this=52baa6b2, name='JAXBMarshallerTransformer', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=[B, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, sourceTypes=[SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}]}

Root Exception stack trace:
  org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: An invalid return type "class [B" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer"
```

Tried multiple options, adding different transformers in response; nothing works! My flow is finally looking like this:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" basePath="/mule" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<cxf:configuration name="CXF_Configuration" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" initializeStaticBusInstance="false" doc:name="CXF Configuration"/>
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean name="StringToDocumentXfm" class="invoke.StringToDocumentTransformer"/>
</spring:beans>
<mulexml:jaxb-context name="JAXB_Context" packageNames="EmployeeSOAClient" doc:name="JAXB Context"/>
<flow name="mule-testproj-soapclientFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/sample" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="GET"/>
    <set-payload value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.empno]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="getEmployeeDetails" clientClass="EmployeeSOAClient.EmployeeService" port="EmployeePort" wsdlLocation="classpath:Employee.wsdl" doc:name="CXF">
        <cxf:aegis-databinding/>
    </cxf:jaxws-client>
    <outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/EmployeeSOA/services/Employee" doc:name="Generic" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    <response>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <invoke name="Invoke" object-ref="StringToDocumentXfm" method="covertStringToDocument" methodArguments="#[payload]" methodArgumentTypes="java.lang.String"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
        <logger message="Output after DOM to XML: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </response>
</flow>
```

What am i missing?

Thanks,
Aneesh.

Comment: Wanted to add, I tried this and still getting the same error:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjulcrt5fDUAhVBiVQKHd6cDi8QFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F30387759%2Fmule-transformerexception-an-invalid-return-type-class-b-was-specified-for-t&usg=AFQjCNFQV0ObOgfz_RFB_Arn0DzPrzC6bQ

Comment: can you post snippet of your response related code

Answer (score 0):

JAXBMarshallerTransformer does not know how to transform to a byte array ("class [B"). Try setting the Return Class to java.lang.String